# Visual Studio não compila para Windows Phone 8

Tags: visual-studio, unity3d, compiladores

Estou enfrentando um problema com o **Visual Studio 2013 Update 4**, ao tentar compilar um projeto para Windows Phone 8, ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> The"CompileXaml" task failed
>   unexpectedly.System.IO.FileNotFoundException:Could not load file or
>   assembly'XamlServicesWP, Version= 11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.The system
>   cannot find the specified file.File name:'XamlServicesWP, Version=
>   11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'Serverstack trace:     at
>   Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.GenerateCode(ITaskItem
>   item,Boolean isApplication)   at
>   Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.Execute()   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md,Object[] args,Object server,Object[]&amp; outArgs)   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg,IMessage retMsg)   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp;
>   msgData,Int32 type)   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
>   atMicrosoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.&lt;ExecuteInstantiatedTask&gt;d__20.MoveNext()WRN:Assembly
>   binding logging is turned OFF.To enable assembly bind failure
>   logging,set the registry value
>   HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog to 1.Note:Thereis
>   some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging.To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].MyProject

Já tentei reinstalar o mesmo, mas nada funcionou, projetos do 8.1 compilam normalmente, porém preciso do compilador do 8 funcionando para compilar jogos feitos no Unity 3D, como consigo resolver esse erro? A outra maneira de compilar o projeto gerado pelo Unity? Talvez pelo Visual Studio 2015?

Por favor, me ajudem, o Unity é a única ferramenta de desenvolvimento de jogos que eu me sinto à vontade. O problema deve estar ligado ao SDK do 8, meu computador é 32bits, e o SDK funcional em apenas 64 bits, porém já consegui fazer ele compilar esses projetos, depois que formatei o computador não consigo mais, há algum SDK ou algo do tipo? Uso o Windows 8.1 (o mesmo do anterior, quando funcionava).